# Trying to get Feeds to import HTML?

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm currently trying to import a large amount of data, including substantial amounts of html coded text into nodes in drupal. When I run the importer the view shows the contents of fields, but where the html tags are all visible with no formatting at all. Also when you go in to look at the node in edit the html fields are completely empty.

I'm not sure what would be causing this. Using Drupal 7.53 [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) 7.x-2.0-beta [Feeds extensible parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) 7.x-1.0-alpha and [feeds tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper).

Comment: Did you set the Input Format to "Full HTML"?

Comment: No, I've been using Filtered HTML.

Comment: Does it work as expected when you change to Full HTML?

Comment: Nope, it's just three empty fields with nothing to edit while I look at the node outside of edit it's got all the html and everything on display, no tags being formatted or anything.

I remember having a similar issue like this once before but heck if I know how I solved it.